# Is there a way to access mixed-in components when the original variable has a default coercion?

Tags: mixins, raku

For instance, in this case:

```
my @list = (2,) but "bar";
put @list.Str «2␤»
```

There does not seem to be a way to access the "bar" component. Am I missing something? Same will happen, for instance, with `Set`

```
my @list = (2,3) but Set(4,5);
put @list.Set; # OUTPUT: «3 2␤»
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assignment is a copying operation, so:

```
my @a = something;
```

Creates an `Array` in `@a`, iterates `something`, and stores each element in `@a`. If binding is used instead:

```
my @list := (2,) but "bar";
put @list.Str;
```

Then the list with the mixin is bound to the symbol `@list`, and the output is:

```
bar
```

Comment: But that means that the mix-in goes to the first element?

Comment: No, it goes on the `List` as a whole. In the case where we assign, the `List` on the right is only used for its contents, then becomes unreachable.

Comment: I find this extremely confusing. If I run `my @list := (2,) but "bar"; say @list; put @list;` Rakudo returns `(2)` for the `say` call but `bar` for the `put` call.  If I run either `say` or `put` on `@list.Str` Rakudo returns `bar`.  If I run either `say` or `put` on `@list.raku` Rakudo returns `(2,)`. Is there any convenient (mnemonic) way of remembering which call returns what?

Comment: `$something but "a string"` is short for `$something but role { method Str() { "a string" } }` - that is, it changes how the object will coerce to a `Str`. The `print` function coerces its argument to `Str`. The `put` function - short for "print using terminator" - also does, since it's a form of `print`. By contrast, `say` calls the `gist` method, as in "give me [the gist of it](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gist)". The role we 
mixed in changes nothing about that.

Comment: @jubilatious1 The memory joggers I use... The `p*t` routines (`put` and `print`) are relatively low level "mechanical" operations and use the correspondingly low level "mechanical" coercion to a "string" (`.Str`) view of some value. In contrast, `say` is a relatively high level "human" action and uses the correspondingly high level "human" action of constructing the "gist" (`.gist`) of some value. Also, the way I remember which add a newline is that it's the two routines with just three characters (`put` and `say`), which makes sense because Huffman coding suggests they should be short.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** I think I'm now closer to understanding what you meant. I share various solutions based on that understanding at the start of this answer. (The rest of this answer is perhaps now mostly moot, but I've left it in because I think it still has some value, especially the apparent bug which still baffles me.)

## Some solutions to what I now think you want

```
role foo { method Str { 42 } }
...
say @bar.Str; # 42
```

where the `...` is suitably filled in, eg one of:

- ```
  class List2 is List does foo {}
  my @bar is List2;
  ```

  What this does, and when:

  - Creates a new container type `List2` composing `List` with role `foo`.
  - *Permanently* "binds" the variable `@bar` to a new instance of the new container type.
  - All of this happens at *compile-time*.
- ```
  my @bar is List;
  @bar does foo;
  ```

  What this does, and when:

  - *Permanently* "binds" the variable `@bar` to a new instance of `List` *at compile-time*.
  - *Permanently* mixes `foo` into *the same* `List` instance *at run-time*.
- ```
  my @bar := (1,2) but foo
  ```

  What this does, and when:

  - Constructs a new `List` instance *at compile-time* from the literal (`(1,2)`).
  - Constructs a *new* instance at *run-time* that's a *clone* of the `List` constructed from the list literal *but* with the `foo` role mixed in.
  - *Temporarily* "binds" the variable `@bar` to the *new* `List` / `foo` object (`(1,2) but foo`).

## My original answer

The code you shared, and its behaviour, is mostly basic ordinary behaviour. jnthn's answer explains these basic aspects. This answer provides a bit more detail and notes one part that surprised me and might be a bug.

> Is there a way to access mixed-in components when the original variable has a default coercion?

I think I see something unexpected going on that might be what you're talking about. But I wouldn't describe it as "default coercion" given that both "default" and "coercion" already have specific meanings in Raku, and it's not to do with those. Modulo the strange behaviour it's just Raku's ordinary semantics for assigning a plural value to a plural variable.

> For instance, in this case:

```
my @list = (2,) but "bar";
```

jnthn's answer explains why that's not going to work. In a nutshell the mixin is on the plural value, not on each of the elements *within* that plural value, so it won't get copied as part of the assignment. Your code is "broken" before you start.

You *could* reasonably write something like this and expect it to work:

```
my @list = (2,) Zbut "bar";
put @list.Str; # «bar␤»
```

The `Z` in the first line *distributes* the `but` over the singular elements in the plural `List` value using [zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_(computer_science)) semantics. There's only one element -- `2` -- but it also works if there are more:

```
my @list = 2,3 Zbut "bar", "foo";
put @list.Str; # «bar foo␤»
```

It's useful to be clear about what's happening in that second line.

The `.Str` method is being called on a *plural* value (an `Array` that gets implicitly created and bound to `@list` as part of declaring `my @list`).

As with most programming languages, each routine in Raku gets to decide what it's going to do based primarily on its arguments. And like most PLs with methods, methods can do perhaps surprisingly different things depending on their invocant.

In Raku the `.Str` method, when called with a *plural* value/variable invocant *distributes* a `.Str` to each element in that plural invocant. (And if any of its elements is itself another plural that call will recursively do the same to its elements.) When all is done, the series of resulting individual strings are concatenated with a space between each.

> Same will happen, for instance, with `Set`

As before, you would again need to distribute the mixin to the individual elements in the first line to have any chance of things working out:

```
my @list = (2,3) Zbut Set(4,5);
```

But now the *second* line still won't do what you're expecting:

```
put @list.Set; # OUTPUT: «3 2␤»
```

The issue is that this time you're dealing with `.Set`.

Calling `.Set` on a plural is not like calling `.Str` on a plural. It has completely different semantics. What it does is construct a set from the plural value's collection of elements. Thus:

```
say (1,2,3).Set; # Set(1 2 3)
```

Hopefully this has all made sense thus far.

Here's where we arrive at what has surprised me. This seems to work:

```
my @list = 2 but Set(4,5);
put @list[0].^name;       # OUTPUT: «Int+{<anon|1>}␤»
put @list[0].Set;         # OUTPUT: «4 5␤»
put @list[0].Set.^name;   # OUTPUT: «Set␤»
```

But if we change the first line, things don't work as I would expect:

```
my @list = (2,3) Zbut Set(4,5);
put @list[0].^name;       # OUTPUT: «Int+{<anon|1>}␤»
put @list[0].Set;         # OUTPUT: «2␤»
put @list[0].Set.^name;   # OUTPUT: «Set␤»
```

That's baffling me. I will sleep on it. But right now that seems like it might be a bug.

Comment: Theoretically, mixins are roles; you should be able to mix in roles into any kind of variable, right? I'd like to mix "bar" into the `List`, not the individual components.

Comment: @jjmerelo It's not really about variables, nor really containers. It's just about values. But I've edited my answer and I'm hoping it clears things up. PLMK if I have or haven't understood what you're after. (I'm still baffled by the `Set` issue I encountered but it may well be irrelevant to your needs.)

Comment: But the problem is still where you mix in a role into a value that has a default coercion to that role. A Num does not have a .Set method defined, so no big deal. A list does have it.

Comment: @jjmerelo I'm not seeing a problem. `my @list := List(1,2) but Set(4,5); # Set (4,5)`. Given `A but B`, or `A does B`, method lookup starts with `B`, not `A`. I now understand what you mean by "default coercion", but the `.Set` method of `List` is just the nature of methods. They're polymorphic. It's no different to `.Str`, which works fine. On a `42` it converts it to `'42'`. On `42, 99` it converts it to `'42 99'`. That's the essence of methods. You don't *have* to use OO and methods in Raku, but many of its built in features do, so you'll have to create functions if you wish to avoid OO.

Comment: OK, I see you're using binding, not assignment here. Assignment would just look up the method on the container, which would default to `A.method`.

Comment: @jjmerelo There are four unrelated topics. You seem to be mixing them up. ① Assignment means assume the LHS of an `=` is a container and ask it to copy elements from the RHS in to itself. Binding means bind the LHS to the RHS. ② Resolving `foo.bar` means looking up `.bar` on the single element of a `Scalar` if `foo` is bound to a `Scalar`, or, if not, looking up `.bar` on whatever is bound to `foo`. ③ Variables are always bound to a value, which may be a container. ④ Mixins alter a value. /// These are 4 utterly separate features, although they work nicely together. Don't mentally mix them up.