# Is there a convenient way to replicate R's concept of 'named vectors' in Raku, possibly using Mixins?

Tags: r, oop, vector, mixins, raku

Recent questions on StackOverflow pertaining to [Mixins](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#Mixins) in Raku have piqued my interest as to whether Mixins can be applied to replicate features present in other programming languages.

For example, in the R-programming language, elements of a vector can be given a name (i.e. an attribute), which is very convenient for data analysis. For an excellent example see: ["How to Name the Values in Your Vectors in R"](https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-name-the-values-in-your-vectors-in-r/) by Andrie de Vries and Joris Meys, who illustrate this feature using `R`'s built-in `islands` dataset. Below is a more prosaic example (code run in the R-REPL):

```
> #R-code
> x <- 1:4
> names(x) <- LETTERS[1:4]
> str(x)
 Named int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "A" "B" "C" "D"
> x
A B C D 
1 2 3 4 
> x[1]
A 
1 
> sum(x)
[1] 10
```

Below I try to replicate `R`'s 'named-vectors' using the same `islands` dataset used by de Vries and Meys. While the script below runs and (generally, see #3 below) produces the desired/expected output, I'm left with three main questions, at bottom:

```
#Raku-script below;

put "Read in data.";

my $islands_A = <11506,5500,16988,2968,16,184,23,280,84,73,25,43,21,82,3745,840,13,30,30,89,40,33,49,14,42,227,16,36,29,15,306,44,58,43,9390,32,13,29,6795,16,15,183,14,26,19,13,12,82>.split(","); #Area

my $islands_N = <<"Africa" "Antarctica" "Asia" "Australia" "Axel Heiberg" "Baffin" "Banks" "Borneo" "Britain" "Celebes" "Celon" "Cuba" "Devon" "Ellesmere" "Europe" "Greenland" "Hainan" "Hispaniola" "Hokkaido" "Honshu" "Iceland" "Ireland" "Java" "Kyushu" "Luzon" "Madagascar" "Melville" "Mindanao" "Moluccas" "New Britain" "New Guinea" "New Zealand (N)" "New Zealand (S)" "Newfoundland" "North America" "Novaya Zemlya" "Prince of Wales" "Sakhalin" "South America" "Southampton" "Spitsbergen" "Sumatra" "Taiwan" "Tasmania" "Tierra del Fuego" "Timor" "Vancouver" "Victoria">>; #Name

"----".say;

put "Count elements (Area): ", $islands_A.elems; #OUTPUT 48
put "Count elements (Name): ", $islands_N.elems; #OUTPUT 48

"----".say;

put "Create 'named vector' array (and output):\n";
my @islands;
my $i=0;
for (1..$islands_A.elems) { 
    @islands[$i] := $islands_A[$i] but $islands_N[$i].Str;
    $i++;
};

say "All islands (returns Area): ",     @islands;             #OUTPUT: returns 48 areas (above)
say "All islands (returns Name): ",     @islands>>.Str;       #OUTPUT: returns 48 names (above)
say "Islands--slice (returns Area): ",  @islands[0..3];       #OUTPUT: (11506 5500 16988 2968)
say "Islands--slice (returns Name): ",  @islands[0..3]>>.Str; #OUTPUT: (Africa Antarctica Asia Australia)
say "Islands--first (returns Area): ",  @islands[0];          #OUTPUT: 11506
say "Islands--first (returns Name): ",  @islands[0]>>.Str;    #OUTPUT: (Africa)

put "Islands--first (returns Name): ",  @islands[0];          #OUTPUT: Africa
put "Islands--first (returns Name): ",  @islands[0]>>.Str;    #OUTPUT: Africa
```

1. Is there a simpler way to write the Mixin loop `...$islands_A[$i] but $islands_N[$i].Str;`? Can the loop be obviated entirely?
2. Can a `named-vector` or `nvec` wrapper be written around `put` that will return `(name)\n(value)` in the same manner that R does, even for single elements? Might Raku's `Pair` method be useful here?
3. Related to #2 above, calling `put` on the single-element `@islands[0]` returns the name `Africa` not the Area value `11506`. [Note this doesn't happen with the call to `say`]. Is there any simple code that can be implemented to ensure that `put` always returns (numeric) `value` or always returns (Mixin) `name` for all-lengthed slices of an array?

Comment: Recent related Raku 'Mixin' questions on SO: 1.  [Is there a straightforwad way to check if something is a mixin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66886026/7270649) and 2. [Is there a way to access mixed-in components when the original variable has a default coercion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66887685/7270649)

Answer (score 9):

1. Is there a simpler way?
   **Yes** using the zip meta operator `Z` combined with infix `but`

   ```raku
   my @islands = $islands_A[] Z[but] $islands_N[];
   ```
2. Why don't you modify the array to change the format?
3. `put` calls `.Str` on the value it gets, `say` calls `.gist`

If you want `put` to output some specific text, make sure that the `.Str` method outputs that text.

I don't think you actually want put to output that format though. I think you want `say` to output that format.
That is because `say` is for humans to understand, and you want it nicer for humans.

---

When you have a question of “Can Raku do **X**” the answer is invariable yes, it's just a matter of how much work would it be, and if you would still call it Raku at that point.

The question you really want to ask is how easy it is to do **X**.

---

I went and implemented *something* like that link you provided talks about.

Note that this was just a quick implementation that I created right before bed. So think of this as a first rough draft.

If I were actually going to do this for-real, I would probably throw this away and start over after spending days learning enough R to figure out what it is actually doing.

```raku
class NamedVec does Positional does Associative {
  has @.names is List;
  has @.nums is List handles <sum>;
  has %!kv is Map;

  class Partial {
    has $.name;
    has $.num;
  }

  submethod TWEAK {
    %!kv := %!kv.new: @!names Z=> @!nums;
  }

  method from-pairlist ( +@pairs ) {
    my @names;
    my @nums;
    for @pairs -> (:$key, :$value) {
      push @names, $key;
      push @nums, $value;
    }
    self.new: :@names, :@nums
  }

  method from-list ( +@list ){
    my @names;
    my @nums;
    for @list -> (:$name, :$num) {
      push @names, $name;
      push @nums, $num;
    }
    self.new: :@names, :@nums
  }

  method gist () {
    my @widths = @!names».chars Zmax @!nums».chars;
    sub infix:<fmt> ( $str, $width is copy ){
      $width -= $str.chars;
      my $l = $width div 2;
      my $r = $width - $l;
      (' ' x $l) ~ $str ~ (' ' x $r)
    }
    (@!names Zfmt @widths) ~ "\n" ~ (@!nums Zfmt @widths)
  }

  method R-str () {
    chomp qq :to/END/
    Named num [1:@!nums.elems()] @!nums[]
     - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:@!names.elems()] @!names.map(*.raku)
    END
  }

  method of () {}
  method AT-POS ( $i ){
    Partial.new: name => @!names[$i], num => @!nums[$i]
  }
  method AT-KEY ( $name ){
    Partial.new: :$name, num => %!kv{$name}
  }
}

multi sub postcircumfix:<{ }> (NamedVec:D $v, Str:D $name){
  $v.from-list: callsame
}
multi sub postcircumfix:<{ }> (NamedVec:D $v, List \l){
  $v.from-list: callsame
}
 

my $islands_A = <11506,5500,16988,2968,16,184,23,280,84,73,25,43,21,82,3745,840,13,30,30,89,40,33,49,14,42,227,16,36,29,15,306,44,58,43,9390,32,13,29,6795,16,15,183,14,26,19,13,12,82>.split(","); #Area
my $islands_N = <<"Africa" "Antarctica" "Asia" "Australia" "Axel Heiberg" "Baffin" "Banks" "Borneo" "Britain" "Celebes" "Celon" "Cuba" "Devon" "Ellesmere" "Europe" "Greenland" "Hainan" "Hispaniola" "Hokkaido" "Honshu" "Iceland" "Ireland" "Java" "Kyushu" "Luzon" "Madagascar" "Melville" "Mindanao" "Moluccas" "New Britain" "New Guinea" "New Zealand (N)" "New Zealand (S)" "Newfoundland" "North America" "Novaya Zemlya" "Prince of Wales" "Sakhalin" "South America" "Southampton" "Spitsbergen" "Sumatra" "Taiwan" "Tasmania" "Tierra del Fuego" "Timor" "Vancouver" "Victoria">>; 

# either will work
#my $islands = NamedVec.from-pairlist( $islands_N[] Z=> $islands_A[] );
my $islands = NamedVec.new( names => $islands_N, nums => $islands_A );

put $islands.R-str;

say $islands<Asia Africa Antarctica>;

say $islands.sum;
```

Comment: I'm unable to compute a sum on your $islands object, e.g. testing `$islands.sum.say;` gives error `Cannot resolve caller...`.

Comment: @jubilatious1 Like I said, this was just before bed; so it accounts for only about an hours worth of work. I also said that it would take days of work before actually starting on a more correct implementation. … That said a quick fix is to add `handles <sum>` to the `@.nums` array.

Comment: no worries, I'm still going through your code! Essentially `R` allows you to create a name alias for each data point in a vector (also, everything in `R` is a vector: there are no scalars). I note with interest that you use a `$`-sigiled variable to hold the `islands` data, my immediate impulse is to reach for an `@`-sigiled variable when working between `R` and `Raku`.

Answer (score 7):

A named vector essentially combines a vector with a map from names to integer positions and allows you to address elements by name. Naming a vector alters the behavior of the *vector*, not that of its elements. So in Raku we need to define a role for an array:

```
role Named does Associative {
    has $.names;
    has %!index;

    submethod TWEAK {
        my $i = 0;
        %!index = map { $_ => $i++ }, $!names.list;
    }

    method AT-KEY($key) {
        with %!index{$key} { return-rw self.AT-POS($_) }
        else { self.default }
    }

    method EXISTS-KEY($key) {
        %!index{$key}:exists;
    }

    method gist() {
        join "\n", $!names.join("\t"), map(*.gist, self).join("\t");
    }
}

multi sub postcircumfix:<[ ]>(Named:D \list, \index, Bool() :$named!) {
    my \slice = list[index];
    $named ?? slice but Named(list.names[index]) !! slice;
}

multi sub postcircumfix:<{ }>(Named:D \list, \names, Bool() :$named!) {
    my \slice = list{names};
    $named ?? slice but Named(names) !! slice;
}
```

Mixing in this role gives you most of the functionality of an R named vector:

```
my $named = [1, 2, 3] but Named<first second last>;
say $named;                 # OUTPUT: «first␉second␉last␤1␉2␉3␤»
say $named[0, 1]:named;     # OUTPUT: «first␉second␤1␉2␤»
say $named<last> = Inf;     # OUTPUT: «Inf␤»
say $named<end>:exists;     # OUTPUT: «False␤»
say $named<last end>:named; # OUTPUT: «last␉end␤Inf␉(Any)␤»
```

As this is just a proof of concept, the `Named` role doesn't handle the naming of non-existing elements well. It also doesn't support modifying a slice of names. It probably *does* support creating a [pun](https://docs.raku.org/language/objects#Automatic_role_punning) that can be mixed into more than one list.

Note that this implementation relies on the undocumented fact that the [subscript operators](https://docs.raku.org/language/subscripts) are multis. If you want to put the role and operators in a separate file, you probably want to apply the `is export` trait to the operators.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the most optimal way of doing it (or what you're specifically looking for) but as soon as I saw this particular problem's statement, the first thing that came to mind were [Raku's allomorphs](https://docs.raku.org/language/numerics#Allomorphs), which are types with two related values that are accessible separately depending on context.

```
my $areas = (11506,5500,16988,2968,16,184,23,280,84,73,25,43,21,82,3745,840,13,30,30,89,40,33,49,14,42,227,16,36,29,15,306,44,58,43,9390,32,13,29,6795,16,15,183,14,26,19,13,12,82);
my $names = <"Africa" "Antarctica" "Asia" "Australia" "Axel Heiberg" "Baffin" "Banks" "Borneo" "Britain" "Celebes" "Celon" "Cuba" "Devon" "Ellesmere" "Europe" "Greenland" "Hainan" "Hispaniola" "Hokkaido" "Honshu" "Iceland" "Ireland" "Java" "Kyushu" "Luzon" "Madagascar" "Melville" "Mindanao" "Moluccas" "New Britain" "New Guinea" "New Zealand (N)" "New Zealand (S)" "Newfoundland" "North America" "Novaya Zemlya" "Prince of Wales" "Sakhalin" "South America" "Southampton" "Spitsbergen" "Sumatra" "Taiwan" "Tasmania" "Tierra del Fuego" "Timor" "Vancouver" "Victoria">;

my @islands;

for (0..^$areas) -> \i {
    @islands[i] := IntStr.new($areas[i], $names[i]);   
}

say "Areas: ",       @islands>>.Int;
say "Names: ",       @islands>>.Str;
say "Areas slice: ", (@islands>>.Int)[0..3];
say "Names slice: ", (@islands>>.Str)[0..3];
say "Areas first: ", (@islands>>.Int)[0];
say "Names first: ", (@islands>>.Str)[0];
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, but IntStr won't apparently handle non-integers. Changing the first area value to 11506.5 results in the error `Type check failed in binding to parameter '$i'; expected Int but got Rat (11506.5)`.

Comment: Use of the sigil-less (iterator) variable `i` is a nice touch (declared with `\i`). Of course, Raku being a Perl-family language, `$i` works  just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just do something like this:

```
class MyRow {
    has Str      $.island is rw;
    has Numeric  $.area   is rw;

    method Str {
        $!island;
        }

    method Numeric { 
        +$!area;
        }

    # does Cool coercion of strings that look numeric
    submethod BUILD ( Numeric(Cool) :$!area, :$!island ) {
    }; 
} 

class MyTable {
    has        @.data;                     
    has MyRow  @.rows  is rw;
    has        %!lookup;

    submethod TWEAK {
        @!rows = gather 
        for @!data -> ( $island, $area ) {
            my $row = MyRow.new( :$island, :$area );
            %!lookup{ $island } = $row;
            take $row;
        }
    }

    method find_island( $island ) {
        return %!lookup{ $island };
    }
}
```

To set up a table:

```
my @raw = @island_names Z @island_areas;
my $table = MyTable.new( data => @raw );
```

Accessing the rows of the table by name:

```
my $row = $table.find_island('Africa');
say $row;   # MyRow.new(island => "Africa", area => 11506)
```

Using the row element like a string gets you the name,
using it like a number gets you the area:

```
say ~$row;  # Africa
say +$row;  # 11506
```

One of the features here is that you can add more fields to your
rows, you're not constrained to just a value and a name.

The "find_island" method uses an internal %lookup hash to index
the rows by island name, but unlike a simple hash solution
there's no uniqueness constraint: if you have a duplicate island
name, "find_island" will locate the latest row in the set, but
the other row would still be there.

Caveat: I haven't thought much about how well this supports
dynamically adding more rows to the table.

Comment: I guess they're best referred to as `named vectors` (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#attr-names ). Use of the word `row` may be confusing: what if two Raku `rows` are imported into R and bound into a 2-column table using R's `cbind()` (column-bind) function?

Comment: Very glad to see your method handles duplicates (i.e. no uniqueness constraint).